# Hadamard Product Represented as "Simpler" Operations

Tags: linear-algebra, hadamard-product

Given matrices $A$ and $B$, the *Hadamard product* $A\circ B$ is given by $(A\circ B)_{ij}=A_{ij}\cdot B_{ij}$ (if you ask an ordinary middle schooler, this would be the "most natural" definition of matrix multiplication, haha.)

Does anyone know if it is possible to represent $A\circ B$ as a combination of other widely used matrix operations, such as addition, multiplication, taking determinant and taking inverse?

Comment: No. All of those operations behave well with respect to conjugation, and the Hadamard product doesn't.

Comment: One should add that the matrices are of the same size, in order for the definition to apply. Also, if they are just numbers, then this is the ordinary multiplication...

Comment: Per chance, restricted to some subgroups of the matrix group, this representation is possible?? Such as the Heisenberg group??

Comment: @awllower: certainly the diagonal matrices...

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: Indeed, thanks.