# Turn cost function into a matrix multiplication

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, machine-learning, least-squares

I have a cost function

$$
E = \sum_{i,j} s_{i,j}(y_{i,j} - f_{i, j})^2
$$

where 
$$
f_{i,j} = \mathbf{u}_i^\top \mathbf{v}_j
$$

I want to turn the objective function into a form including only matrices and vectors however I am struggling to do it.

I have turned the cost function into another form:

$$ 
E  = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^m s_{i,j}(y_{i,j} - f_{i,j})^2
$$

Although I have tried to create vectors (for the j counter) and then matrices (for the i counter) using the vectors, I don't think that this was the right approach.

Answer (score 2):

Let $(U,V)$ be the matrices whose columns consist of the $(u_i, v_j)$ vectors.

Then you can use the [Frobenius (:) Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Frobenius_product) and the [Hadamard ($\circ$) Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Hadamard_product) to write the cost function in matrix form
$$\eqalign{
  E &= S:(Y-U^TV)\circ(Y-U^TV) \cr\cr
}$$
Since the matrix of all ones is the identity for the Hadamard product ($1\circ S=S$), and the Hadamard and Frobenius products are mutually commutative ($A\circ B:C=A:B\circ C$), the cost function can also be written as
$$\eqalign{
  E &= 1:S\circ(Y-U^TV)\circ(Y-U^TV) \cr\cr
}$$
I mention this because most computer languages have operations which map directly to this form.
For example, in Julia you can write

```
   E = sum(S .* (Y-U'*V) .* (Y-U'*V))
```

Matlab is very similar.

Comment: Can you please give a solution without making use of the Frobenius Product and Handmard product?

Comment: @Old not generally, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/179325/hadamard-product-represented-as-simpler-operations