# Diagonalization and the Hadamard product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization, hadamard-product

Let $B \in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ be unitarily diagonalizable such that $B=V\Lambda V^*$. Let $A=B\circ B$ where $\circ$ accounts for the Hadamard product. Then we can say that $A$ is also unitarily diagonalizable. I need a hint for unitarily diagonalization of the matrix $A$ based on $V$ and $\Lambda$. Can we do that? At least can we get any information about the eigenvalues of $A$ based on eigenvalues of $B$?

Comment: Probably there is no way to do it in general: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/2578/eigenvalues-and-determinant-of-a-hadamard-product-of-matrices

Comment: See also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/207836/hadamard-product-and-eigendecomposition and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/179325/hadamard-product-represented-as-simpler-operations

Comment: @jobe:  Thank you.